# How does an integer store a literal (eg var x = 0)

Tags: swift

when i write `var x = 0`

I know that `x` is an object that has properties and methods (created from Int Structure).

**Where and how does x store the 0 ?**

Is the 0 stored as a **property** of x ?

If yes, what would be the **type** of that property ?

If not, where is it stored ?

Comment: `Int` conforms to [`IntegerLiteralConvertible`](http://nshipster.com/swift-literal-convertible/) so the compiler knows how to convert a fixed value like 0 to an `Int` struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` is not an object, strictly speaking. "Object" is a name we give to *instances* of classes, *not* structs. `x` is an *instance* of the `Int` struct.

The `Int` structure wraps a `Builtin` integer type, and defines a bunch of methods you can call on it. That builtin integer literal type isn't accessible from Swift (nor is there a reason for it to be). Like all structures, instances of `Int` are stored on the runtime stack. They're not objects on the heap like `Integer` in Java, for example.

You can see the [implementation details of `(U)Int(8/16/32/64)` here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/FixedPoint.swift.gyb). This file uses the Generate Your Boilerplate (GYB) preprocessor created by the Swift team to generate `.swift` files from `.swift.gyb` template files.
On [line 221](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/FixedPoint.swift.gyb#L221), you can see the property `_value` of type `Builtin.${BuiltinName}`. The GYB preprocessor expands this out so that `Int` has a `_value` of type `Builtin.Int`, `Int64` has `Built.Int64`, etc.

Comment: IIRC the `value` property used to be public, actually. I can't remember when they hid it.

Comment: @matt What would you want it for?

Comment: You wouldn't, that's why they hid it. But it meant that the answer to the OP's question was plainly visible.

Comment: `_value` is actually accessible in the swift repl

Comment: Yes, they haven't gotten around to making underscored members totally inaccessible. They are working on that, but for now they need them accessible for testing purposes. But it isn't in the header. What I'm saying is, it used to be right there in the header, so that it was perfectly obvious how numbers worked.

Comment: That's neat, I hope they keep a way to run the repl in this kind if transparent mode. It's fun to poke around these things :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128977/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-matt).